# React Native Image Component Not Displaying Images from api

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm encountering an issue in my React Native application where the Image component is not displaying images fetched from an API. The image URLs are logged correctly, and the API appears to be working fine.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';

const Product = (props) => {
  console.log('Product Image URL:', props.productImage);

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5}>
      <View style={styles.productContainer}>
        <Image
          source={{
            uri: props.productImage,
          }}
          style={styles.productImage}
        />
        <Text style={styles.productTitle}>{props.title}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.productPrice}>€ {props.price}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  productContainer: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    borderRadius: 8,
    padding: 10,
    margin: 6,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  productImage: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
  },
  productTitle: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginTop: 5,
    width: 155,
    height: 90,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  productPrice: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: '#888',
  },
});
```

I have tried the following steps:

- Confirmed that the image URLs are correct.
- Tested with a local image, and it renders successfully.
- Checked for any styling or layout issues within the components. However, the images fetched from the API are still not visible.

Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

for the following code:

```
const Product = (props) => {
  console.log('Product Image URL:', props.productImage);

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5}>
      <View style={styles.productContainer}>
        <Image
          style={styles.productImage}
          source={{
            uri: props.productImage,
          }}
          onError={(error) => console.error('Image load error:', error.nativeEvent)}
          />
          <Text style={styles.productTitle}>{props.title}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.productPrice}>€ {props.price}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

props.productImage give me the right url, but error.nativeElement shows me an error saying "Image load error: {"error": "Failed to connect to sport.ddev.site/127.0.0.1:80"}"

Comment: What is the content-type of the image that you are testing with (not its file extension, but the content-type header when the image gets fetched by any client)?  And when you say "image fetched from API" -- do you mean the URL (string) is fetched from the API or that there is some API that is fetching the actual binary blob of the image?  Or are you simply referring to the use of `source={{uri: props.productImage}}`?

Comment: BTW: are you using Expo?  If not, consider it.

Comment: The images I'm testing with have varying content types, including `image/jpg`, `image/jpeg`, and `image/png`, and the API I'm using returns a URL (string) for the image, and I set the `Image` component source using `source={{uri: props.productImage}}`. Yes i'm. using expo! :)

Comment: It will probably be nothing but could you add `flex: 1` to the `productContainer` style

Comment: What happens if  you try to access the image URL using a non-authenticated client such as `curl`, `wget` or Postman (without any type of authentication)

Comment: Im very new to react so i'm not sure if i'm answering correctly here, but when i write the api which is https://sport.ddev.site/api/products i get a json that looks like this:      {
            "id": 523,
            "title": "Ccm Fitlite 50 Hockey Helmet",
            "categoryTitle": "Ice Hockey Helmets",
            "price": 42.5,
            "productImage": "http://sport.ddev.site/_mobilepreview/Ccm-Fitlite-50-Hockey-Helmet.jpeg"
        },

then when i try to access http://sport.ddev.site/_mobilepreview/Ccm-Fitlite-50-Hockey-Helmet.jpeg, it shows the actual image aswell.

Comment: @Thomasino73, adding flex:1 didnt do anything :/

Comment: @Mila you could make a `Snack` of your code and share the link so we could experiment in it.